# Create a directory in a function, then return path as a string to caller in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

this is my first time posting here. I don't know if this has been already asked, but I can't find an answer anywhere.

So, I'm trying to make a little script that creates a directory tree, using the root directory I pass as a parameter from the calling function, and then I want to return the full path to the caller function. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
function createLogPath(){
  local __BASE="$1/var/log"
  local __fullPath=$2

  mkdir -p $__BASE

  if [ $? -eq 0]
  then
    __fullPath=$( sed "$__BASE" )
    eval $__fullPath
  fi
}
```

As you can possibly tell by my code, there are several things I still don't grasp about Bash, since I've been only working with it for like a week or something, so I'm doing this script for testing and learning purposes mostly. My intention with this little function is to create a path to store log files at a given location, and then return the full path to the caller function, so that I can use that path to create a log file in '*../var/log*'.

But when I call this function from another script, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
. makedir.sh  # That's the name of the script where createLogPath() is

BASE=$1
RESULT=''

createLogPath $BASE $RESULT

printf "The path is: %s\n" $RESULT
```

This is not printing anything... what I'm trying to do is return the full path to '*../var/log*' as a string, but eval keeps treating $__fullPath as a directory and it's giving me a headache...

As you can see from my code, I have no idea what I'm doing, so please explain what I'm doing wrong as well as the correct way to do what I'm trying to do. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of the call to `sed`? It blocks the script waiting for input as currently written.

Comment: @chepner someone suggested that as a way to turn a path into a string, but that was for another question, I was just trying different solutions and that was the last version of the script I was trying to do, so I left it there. I don't really know what 'sed' is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash function arguments are passed by value, not by reference. That is, assigning a value to the argument inside the function will not affect the variable outside the function.

You have two possibilities to return a string from a bash function:

1. Echo it to the standard output, for example:

   ```
   function createLogPath(){
       local __BASE="$1/var/log"

       mkdir -p $__BASE

       if [ $? -eq 0 ]
       then
           __fullPath=$( sed "$__BASE" )
           echo $__fullPath
       fi
   }
   ```

   and retrieve it with the $() operator, like this:

   ```
   RESULT=$(createLogPath $BASE)
   ```
2. Use export, like this:

   ```
   function createLogPath(){
       local __BASE="$1/var/log"

       mkdir -p $__BASE

       if [ $? -eq 0 ]
       then
           __fullPath=$( sed "$__BASE" )
           export RESULT=$__fullPath
       fi
   }
   ```

(Keeping as closely to your original code although it could be simplified.)

Comment: The `export` isn't necessary. `RESULT` is a global variable by default, and visible to the caller once `createLogPath` returns (assuming it isn't executed in a subshell, such as in a command substitution).

Comment: @Tilman Schmidt dude, thanks a million, the problem was that when I returned the string with 'echo $__fullPath' I wasn't using 'RESULT=$(createLogPath $BASE)' to store it. All I was getting was the path being echoed whenever I called the function, that's why I wasn't using echo in the first place. But you helped me see the light. Thanks a lot.